# Whats difference between delegate trigger and normal trigger to get UITextField on CustomCell from TableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

There are two UITextField instance on UITableViewCell.
I want to get the text of UITextField on CustomCell.
that function is test().

Pattern A is delegate from UITextField,
Pattern B is press cell function.

I tested Pattern B worked, but Pattern A does not work.
I actually want A to work,
This is my question,
Why Pattern A doesnt work?

And, How can I get the text of UITextField on CustomCell from TableViewController?

```
//Only needed code is written.

protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate{
    func getInputed(textField: UITextField)
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell , UITextFieldDelegate{
        override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    if myTextField != nil {

        myTextField.delegate = self
        myTextField2.delegate = self
    }
}

    //the session is to end
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if delegate != nil {
            self.delegate?.getInputed(textField)
        }
        return true
    }


}


class TableViewController: UITableViewController, CustomTableViewCellDelegate{

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
//Im sure I write like this
    cell.delegate = self

}
    //Pattern A
    func getInputed(textField: UITextField){
        test()
    }

    //Pattern B

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        test()

    }


    func test(){
        self.myTableView.reloadData()
        let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as! CustomTableViewCell
        print(cell.myTextField.text)
        print(cell.myTextField.tag)
        print(cell.myTextField2.text)
        print(cell.myTextField2.tag)

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `textFieldShouldEndEditing` is getting called ? Also have you set the object of `TableViewController` as delegate of cell ?

Comment: of course, yes.  textFieldShouldEndEditing is called. just only shows Optional("").

Comment: You mean to say `getInputed` is called with `Pattern A`, but value of `cell.myTextField.text` is `Optional("")` ?

Comment: I added delegate code.

Comment: Can you try using textFieldDidEndEditing instead of textFieldShouldEndEditing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107306/discussion-between-san-and-yosuke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion in comments/chat, I am adding the answer.
Modification of code in following manner works:

```
protocol CustomTableViewCellDelegate{
    func getInputed(cell:CustomTableViewCell)
}

//the session is to end
func textFieldDidEndEditing(cell:CustomTableViewCell) {
    if delegate != nil {
        self.delegate?.getInputed(self)
    }
}

func test(cell:CustomTableViewCell) {
    print(cell.myTextField.text)
    print(cell.myTextField.tag)
    print(cell.myTextField2.text)
    print(cell.myTextField2.tag)

    self.myTableView.reloadData()
}
```